# Raspberry Pi Camera Motion Detection via simple script

Tags: pi-3, pi-4, camera, motion, libcamera

I have started out my simple security camera project. I am able to take a picture and email it so far.
Allegedly most people are using PIR sensors. Do I need a PIR sensor for motion detection?

How can I detect motion with my "Raspberry Pi Camera Module V2"?

I have the Raspberry Pi 3 Model B, any simple scripts appreciated.

Comment: This has really not much to do with the Pi.  I suggest you look at the motion package which will be available on most Linux distributions.

Comment: I saw some examples of people using threshold etc and wasn't really understanding some of their script when reading through it. Do you have a link that i can go to so i can check it out please? Thank you!

Comment: here is one of many articles I found : [http://www.tinkernut.com/portfolio/homemade-motion-detecting-security-camera-part-2-simplecv/](http://www.tinkernut.com/portfolio/homemade-motion-detecting-security-camera-part-2-simplecv/)  @Alex

Comment: Most people are using a PIR because it works pretty well, is easy to set up and costs peanuts. I suggest you do the same, unless you have reasons not to use it, which you should explain.

Answer (score 0):

download the latest os, and check if `libcamera-*` is available in terminal via autocomplete. Several options are available

- libcamera-hello  libcamera-jpeg   libcamera-raw    libcamera-still  libcamera-vid    libcamerify
  If you wonder where raspistill and raspivid went the got replaced by a new stack and i confirm it works well. Python lib not out yet, still you can do motion detection.

Start by reading [doc](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/accessories/camera.html#libcamera-and-libcamera-apps) and then build the binaries into python via [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess)

**Example**:
before: mkdir /home/user/camera; paste motion_detect.json to dir
run via `python capture.py`

```
$ cat motion_detect.json
{
    "motion_detect" :
    {
    "roi_x" : 0,
    "roi_y" : 0,
    "roi_width" : 1,
    "roi_height" : 1,
    "difference_m" : 0.2,
    "difference_c" : 20,
    "region_threshold" : 0.005,
    "frame_period" : 30,
    "hskip" : 2,
    "vskip" : 2,
    "verbose" : 1
    }
}
```

```
import subprocess
import shutil
from datetime import datetime as dt
import os


def printc(s):
    print('\033[1;36mINFO\033[0m ' + s)


def get_sorted_filenames():
    filenames = [s for s in os.listdir('/home/user/camera') if s.startswith('vid')]
    filenames.sort()
    return filenames


def get_last_filenr():
    filenames = get_sorted_filenames()
    if len(filenames) == 0:
        return 0
    return int(filenames[-1].partition('_')[0].removeprefix('vid'))


def start_detect():
    return subprocess.Popen(['libcamera-still',
                             '--timeout', '0',
                             '--nopreview',
                             '--lores-width', '1280', '--lores-height', '720',
                             '--post-process-file', '/home/user/camera/motion_detect.json'],
                            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
                            text=True)


def start_recording():
    filename = f'vid{get_last_filenr() + 1}_{dt.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S")}.h264'
    return subprocess.run(['libcamera-vid', '--timeout', '10000', '--framerate', '3', '-o', filename],
                          text=True, timeout=15, capture_output=True, check=True)


def free_disk_space():
    filenames = get_sorted_filenames()
    if len(filenames) > 100:
        to_delete = filenames[:len(filenames) // 4]
        for filename in to_delete:
            os.remove('/home/user/camera/' + filename)
        print(to_delete)
        printc('Delete done.')


p1 = start_detect()
p2 = None
while True:
    s = p1.stderr.readline()
    print(s, end='')
    if 'Motion detected' in s:
        printc('Motion detected, recording...')
        try:
            p1.terminate()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            p1.kill()
        try:
            p2 = start_recording()
            printc('Video recorded.')
            print(p2)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        p1 = start_detect()
        printc('Motion checking...')

    stats = shutil.disk_usage('/')
    if stats.used / stats.total > 0.9:
        printc('Disk almost full!')
        free_disk_space()
```

The specific motion capture used is found in
https://github.com/raspberrypi/libcamera-apps/blob/main/post_processing_stages/motion_detect_stage.cpp